# Add Role to Registration in WP

Tags: wordpress, registration, buddypress, role

I am looking for a way to add a dropdown for users in the registration form to select their role (except administrator).
Currently running wordpress 4.7.4 with buddypress 2.8.0., found some snippets and such but none of them are actually working.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: so far only found a year old plugin that works on the newer wp / bp versions https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-roles-at-registration/

Answer (score 0):

You have to create user-role.php fileand include it in functions.php file.

```
<?php

if( get_role('subscriber') ){
  remove_role( 'subscriber' );
}
if( get_role('client') ){
  remove_role( 'client' );
}

// Add a Country (Others) role

$result = add_role( 'country', __(

'Country (Others)' ),

array(

'read' => true, // true allows this capability
'edit_posts' => true, // Allows user to edit their own posts
'edit_pages' => true, // Allows user to edit pages
'edit_others_posts' => true, // Allows user to edit others posts not just their own
'create_posts' => true, // Allows user to create new posts
'manage_categories' => true, // Allows user to manage post categories
'publish_posts' => true, // Allows the user to publish, otherwise posts stays in draft mode
'edit_themes' => false, // false denies this capability. User can’t edit your theme
'install_plugins' => false, // User cant add new plugins
'update_plugin' => false, // User can’t update any plugins
'update_core' => false // user cant perform core updates

)

);
```